# how to arrange multidimensional array - Group by value in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to arrange same date items to single index, I have following array -

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 30 Dec 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 84675
                [name] => Item1
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 28 Dec 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 84675
                [name] => item2
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 22 Nov 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2011
                [name] => item3
            )
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [date] => 22 Nov 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 86649
                [name] => item4
            )
    ))
```

I want to arrange this array like -

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 30 Dec 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 84675
                [name] => Item1
            )
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 28 Dec 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 84675
                [name] => item2
            )
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [date] => 22 Nov 2015
        [record] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2011
                [name] => item3
            ),Array
            (
                [id] => 86649
                [name] => item4
            )
    )
)
```

I want to arrange same date items into single index, can anybody please help me.I tried to arrange it using loops but couldn't get success.Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How you are getting the base array?

Comment: Why don't you make the `$res->date` as a `key` in the array?

Comment: Yes @choz , I did the same and it worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it can help

```
<?php 
  $result = array();
  foreach($data as $info)
  {
    $result[$info['date']][] = $info;
  }
  print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasbir Singh, it almost produced the desired array but as exact as I want to.

Comment: okay that's great! I've added print_r(array_values($result)); to re-index it, thanks much Jasbir!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in such a way also. In this way you will be able to get the dates in keys of $record_array and record values in values. Try this..

```
$your_array = array();
$record_array = array();
foreach ($your_array as $value){
    $record_array[$value['date']][] = $value['record'];
}
print_r($record_array);
```

Hope this wil help